# resize animated GIFs with phpthumb

Tags: php

Im trying to use the phpThumb program to re-size an animated gif. But when i use it just as the site explains it in the demo, my re-sized GIF is single frame only.

Anyone have experience with this software that could offer tip?

The line im using is

```
phpthumb.php?src=/anitest/images/animation.gif&w=125&f=gif
```

[Here is link of demo im using](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/demo/phpThumb.demo.demo.php#x10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if you have ImageMagick installed. If you don't then phpThumb will use GD library to resze your images and this library doesn't support animated gifs resizing. There is a nice script in phpThumb (in a `phpThumb.config.php` file) that allows you to analyse your server configuration and check if everything is set up correctly.

Here's the demo of the script: [link](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/demo/phpThumb.demo.check.php)